# Using nanomsg in Kernel-Space

Tags: kernel, nanomsg

I am looking into the feasibility of using `nanomsg` within kernel-space. The idea is to have a kernel process/thread send and receive messages across a `nanomsg` socket to local (user-space) and/or remote `nanomsg` sockets.

I imagine this will not work "right out of the box" and am seeking out tips/hints.

Is this even possible? For example, has someone ever tried building a .ko of `libnanomsg` for use in FreeBSD?

Comment: This is very much related to another question, [Using ZeroMQ in Kernel-Space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25573885). --ap